# SQL Row containing max value per another variable

Tags: sql, datetime, mariadb, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have a basic SQL query but laptop is about to go out the window lol

I have a table

```
ID,     StudentID,      Mark,     DateAdded
1       2               78        19/02/2020 
2       4               43        19/02/2020
3       2               23        19/02/2020
4       5               91        20/03/2020
5       7               56        20/03/2020      
6       9               24        20/03/2020 
7       10              56        12/05/2020
8       10              23        12/05/2020
9       10              78        12/05/2020
10      9               23        12/05/2020
```

What I want to pull out is the entire row which has max score for each unique studentID, so for example

```
ID.     StudentID.      Mark.     DateAdded
1       2               78        19/02/2020
2       4               43        19/02/2020
4       5               91        20/03/2020
5       7               56        20/03/2020
6       9               24        20/03/2020
9       10              78        12/05/2020
```

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What's the expected result if a student has the same, highest Mark on two different dates?

Comment: MariaDB and highest dateadded but that isn't really an issue

Comment: Please mark an answer if you have found any of the questions useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical function `row_number` as follows:

```
Select * from
(select t.*,
       Row_number() over (partition by studentid order by mark desc) as rn
  From t)
Where rn= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your result with a group by, but you can't get the ID and DateAdded column too in this way.

```
   SELECT StudentID, MAX(Mark)
     FROM YourTable
 GROUP BY StudentID
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use function `MAX()` and then a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT StudentID, MAX(Mark) from tableOne GROUP BY studentID
```

Here is a fiddle link:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd8e77/3

Answer (score 0):

I am going to recommend a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.mark = (select max(t1.mark) from mytable t1 where t1.studentid = t.studentid)
```

Why:

- Portability: this works in all versions of MySQL/MariaDB, whereas window functions were introduced in MySQL 8.0 / MariaDB 10.2.2
- Efficiency: you want an index on `(studentid, mark)` (or better yet, `studentid, mark desc)`, so the subquery can take advantage of it. In many situations, the correlated subquery is the most efficient approach at such top-1-per group problem.